# Apache Kafka Cluster from existing Kafka brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to create Kafka cluster from 3 existing brokers and put together all topics from all brokers without data loss?

For example, I have:
Broker1 - TopicA, TopicB
Broker2 - TopicC, TopicD
Broker3 - TopicE, TopicF

What I want to do is to create one cluster, which would consist of TopicA, TopicB, TopicC, TopicD, TopicE, TopicF with evenly distributed partitions.

Is it possible? How can I achieve this? What would be with **consumer_offset** topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use tools like MirrorMaker2 to replicate data into an expanded cluster. It's not possible to have an existing broker join another; you'd need to format its storage, then treat the server as a brand new broker.

You'd also need to use kafka-reassign-partitions to modify replication factor of all topics from 1 to 3